# Is there a configuration file for Numpy?

Tags: python, configuration, numpy, environment-variables, configuration-files

I often use Numpy from the command line and always have to remember to apply some recurrent settings, for example setting the output formatting:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.NaN, precision=3, suppress=True, linewidth=180)
```

Is there a global Numpy config file that is automatically executed for a new Python shell or during import that can execute this? If not, is there an elegant way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of such a configuration file for `numpy` (for `matplotlib` for example you have [the `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)).

But, as a workaround, you can set your [environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) pointing to a Python script that will do whatever you want everytime a Python section starts.

In my case I use it to `import numpy as np`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` as so on... saving a small amount of "overhead" everytime I want to quickly try something on Python.

Example on Windows:

```
set PYTHONSTARTUP=C:\Users\yourlogin\somewhere\startup.py
```

Example on Linux:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/usr/local/bin/startup.py
```

You should set it just once using the "Control Panel\System", for example, on Windows.

Comment: `PYTHONSTARTUP` is run *only* in interactive mode, `python -i xx.py`. Otherwise runs with different `PYTHONSTARTUP`s would be non-reproducible; the downside is that everyone has his/her own Rube Goldberg way to set options and import paths.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a configuration file specifically for numpy, but if you use IPython you could [set up a profile](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/overview.html#profiles) such that these print options are set automatically when you open a new IPython shell.

Create a new profile (you can omit the name to create a default profile)

```
$ ipython profile create fancyprint
```

Then edit the configuration file, which should live in `~/.config/ipython/profile_fancyprint/ipython_config.py`

Uncomment this line:

```
# c.TerminalIPythonApp.exec_lines = []
```

And add the lines you want to execute on startup:

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.exec_lines = [
    'import numpy as np',
    'np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.NaN, precision=3, suppress=True, linewidth=180)'
    ]
```

Then you can launch IPython with the named profile

```
$ ipython --profile=fancyprint
```

Your array printing options should be set automatically.

Comment: And for anyone working interactively with numpy, etc and not using `ipython`, you really, really, really should give it a try.